# Remove extrapolation on PowerBI line chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization

[image]

Hi there, I am trying to show progress achieved (or, 'actuals') against baseline and current forecast lines. I have a table with a long list of activities, each with a baseline & current forecast date, only some which have actual dates.  I am trying to plot where we are cumulatively against baseline.

I have 3 running total measures to plot these lines e.g. the actual line is counted as per the below:

```
Actual Running Total = 
    CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Distinct ID'[Actual Date]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Date'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Date'[Date], MAX('Date'[Date]), DESC)
    ))
```

I want the Actual Running Total line to stop at its highest point, i.e. when it hits 60 I don't want it to extrapolate out to the end of the chart, but still need to see the end of the baseline & current forecast lines

Graph showing where I want it to stop :
[image]

After reading similar problems on here I have tried changing the x-axis type between continuous and categorical but that is not helping

Where we have not completed the activity, the Actual Date column is blank/null

[image]

Comment: Can you share your input ? and your model ?